# Merge your types with existing, Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a interface (below), what I want to achieve is change property `req`, add to it my custom type, per se `req: { session: { userId?: string } }`, is it possible to merge my type and library `Request` type?

```
interface MyContext {
  req: Request;
  res: Response;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When two interfaces share the same name, subsequent property declarations must have the same type. This means it's easy to *add* another property using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but it's not easy to override it.

**When it's an intersection**

If you want to simply add another property to `Request`, you can use declaration merging.

```
declare global {
    interface Request {
        session: {
            userId?: string
        }
    }
}
```

**When it's a union**

In order to override the definitions provided by a third-party library, you need to create your own version for them and include it in your project. There is a downside — they will not be merged together. You need to re-create (or copy-paste) every type definition delivered by `my-module` you care about.

**`my-module.d.ts`**

```
declare module 'my-module' {
  interface MyContext {
    req: Request | { session: { userId?: string } };
    res: Response;
  }
}
```

However, the fact you need to override third-party type definitions almost always indicates one of two things:

- you are not using the library the way it was intended to be used, or
- the type definitions are incorrect and should be fixed upstream.

Comment: In that case, you can augment the built-in `Request` type. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `extends`:

```
interface MyContext extends Request {
  //what ever props you want to add
}
```

Now `MyContext` has all the properties assigned to the `Request` type, as well as whatever you define.

If for some reason you only need specific parts of the `Request` type or you do not want to use interfaces, I'd suggest checking out the `utility-types` library, specifically the `Assign`, `Pick`, and `Omit` types it provides.

You could say:

```
type MyType = { ...whatever props you need to add}
type MyRequest = Assign<Request, MyType>
```

and now `MyRequest` has the props you'd like to add.

You could also pick types from, or remove types from `Request`. Suppose `Request` has a `foo` prop that you want to remove:

```
type MyRequest = Omit<Request, 'foo'>
```

or maybe you only want an imaginary prop called `bar`:

```
type JustBarFromRequest = Pick<Request, 'bar'>
```

and you can `Assign` those new types as you see fit.

If you just need to build on an existing interface then definitely stick with `extends`. If you need to alter and compose props and types then I highly recommend reading about [`utility-types`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utility-types)